# Get AWS SQS queue URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

An AWS SQS queue URL looks like this:

```
sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/1234567890/default_development
```

And here are the parts broken down:

```
Always same | Stored in env var | Always same   | ?          | Stored in env var
sqs         | us-east-1         | amazonaws.com | 1234567890 | default_development
```

So I can reconstruct the queue URL based on things I know except the `1234567890` part.

What is this number and is there a way, if I have my AWS creds in env vars, to get my hands on it without hard-coding another env var?

Answer (score 1):

The 1234567890 should be your AWS account number.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/ImportantIdentifiers.html

Comment: I suspected that the 1234567890 was something like that, but how do I *get* that number? Do I have to hard-code it into my env vars? Seems strange if so.

Comment: The GetUser API call, with no username will return information about the user making the call: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GetUser.html

Comment: @JasonSwett the doc cited in the answer suggests that the fact that you are asking this question means you're planning to do something you should not do: *"In your system, always store the entire queue URL as Amazon SQS returned it to you when you created the queue (for example, http://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/123456789012/queue2). Don't build the queue URL from its separate components each time you need to specify the queue URL in a request because Amazon SQS could change the components that make up the queue URL."*

Comment: Good point @Michael - there is no guarantee that the queue names will always be built that way.

Comment: Ah, good catch. I guess that comment would make an appropriate correct answer to my question if you want to add it as an answer.

Comment: The documentation no longer says that you shouldn't build the queue URL. This probably means that it's now fine to build or hardcode the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the queue URL directly (e.g. you can get it directly from CloudFormation if you create it there) you can call the [GetQueueUrl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_GetQueueUrl.html) API. It takes a parameters of the `QueueName` and optional `QueueOwnerAWSAccountId`. That would be the preferred method of getting the URL. It is true that the URL is a well formed URL based on the account and region, and I wouldn't expect that to change at this point. It is possible that it would be different in a region like the China regions, or the Gov Cloud regions.